# Retrieve a certificate's SHA1 hash from macOS Keychain Access

Tags: x509certificate, keychain

I have many certificates with the same name, but they have different `SHA1` hashes. I know the expiration date of the cert I want to retrieve, but I don't know its `SHA1` hash. I can see the certificate's expiration date in `Keychain Access`, but how do I see find its `SHA1` hash?

Comment: Double clicking a certificate (or clicking the "i" symbol at the bottom of the certificate list) opens a window with information about the certificate. Besides "Trust" there should be another category named "Details". If you open it and scroll down to the very bottom, you should see the SHA-1 fingerprint.

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize it was the same value. Please change this to an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the SHA-1 fingerprint of a certificate in macOS Keychain Access you have to double click the certificate in the list or select it (single click) and click the "i" button at the bottom of the window. This opens a window with additional information about the certificate. Besides "Trust" there should be another collapsible category named "Details". If you expand it and scroll down to the very bottom, you should see the SHA-1 fingerprint.

[image: Screenshot of certificate list in macOS Keychain Access and information window showing the SHA-1 fingerprint of a certificate]