# Retrieve a certificate's SHA1 hash from macOS Keychain Access via Terminal

Tags: certificate, keychain

This answer only provides an answer of a way to get the SHA1 code via Keychain Access UI: [Retrieve a certificate's SHA1 hash from macOS Keychain Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112768/retrieve-a-certificates-sha1-hash-from-macos-keychain-access)

Is there a way to see the SHA1 hash for the certificates via the `security dump-keychain` command or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `security` cli to find a certificate. Providing the right query and the right parameters will output the SHA-1 hash.

```
security find-certificate -Z
```

You can alter the `find-certificate` command to perform a better selection. The `-Z` parameter adds the SHA-1 and SHA-256 hash to the output.

One final remark, [SHA-1 is considered insecure since 2005](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html). I highly recommend switching to SHA-256, which conveniently is also outputted via the `-Z` parameter